# GWT RequestFactory - creating new objects

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

Let's say you have a server-side entity called `MyEntity` and you also have all the related stuff on your client side (`MyEntityProxy` and `MyEntityRequest`).

Consider the case when you'd like to create a new instance of `MyEntity`, but you're not really sure if you're going to persist it (like user clicks "Create new MyEntity" and then after editor appears, user clicks "Cancel").

So, you make a call like `requestContext.create(MyEntityProxy.class)` and you get a new object of type `MyEntityProxy`. Since it's neither persisted yet nor it has version - what behavior should I expect when working with this object? Is it a common practice at all or should I only work with persisted objects - probably, by making all of them have a flag like `boolean reallyExists` or `boolean temporary`?

Comment: Do you have an issue with such a create()d proxy? If so what is it? and otherwise what are you asking for? Also, have you looked at the samples from the GWT SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with new proxy and with proxy that represents entity persisted on server side. So there is really no need to `reallyExists` flag unless you have specific use-case that requires it.